# ReSharper 8.2.3 crashes during startup of Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper-8.0

When I start up my Visual Studio 2008 with ReSharper 8.2.3 using the /Log switch, I can see in the produced log-file, that several exceptions are thrown by ReSharper. I cannot use VS to change any files (typing is not deactivated, but it ignores any non-ascii typing). As soon as I deactivate ReSharper, everything is back to normal.

### devenv.exe /Resharper.LogFile /Resharper.LogLevel Verbose output:

[snipped - startup info and threads logging verbose....]

```
11:18:06 AM.510: Thread:1: [VsShortcutManager] CurrentInputLanguage: de-CH (Swiss German)
11:18:06 AM.510: Thread:1: [VsShortcutManager] DefaultInputLanguage: en-US (US)
11:18:06 AM.579: Thread:1: EXCEPTION: Culture ID 8192 (0x2000) is not a supported culture. Parameter name: culture
Culture ID 8192 (0x2000) is not a supported culture. Parameter name: culture

--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [ArgumentException]
Message = “Culture ID 8192 (0x2000) is not a supported culture.”
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = System.ArgumentException
HResult = COR_E_ARGUMENT=E_INVALIDARG=80070057
Source = mscorlib
ParamName = culture
StackTraceString = “
  at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(Int32 cultureId, Boolean useUserOverride)
     at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
     at System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.get_Culture()
     at JetBrains.VsIntegration.ActionManagement.VsShortcutManager.<OnBeforeBulkShortcutsChange>b__d(InputLanguage lang)
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func, Func`2 resultSelector)
     at JetBrains.Util.CollectionUtil.AggregateString[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, StringBuilder seed, String separator, Func`3 funcAppend, Func`2 funcConvert)
     at JetBrains.Util.CollectionUtil.AggregateString[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, String separator, Func`3 funcAppend)
     at JetBrains.VsIntegration.ActionManagement.VsShortcutManager.OnBeforeBulkShortcutsChange()
     at JetBrains.VsIntegration.ActionManagement.VsActionLoader.OnBeforeLoadActions(ICollection`1 infos)
     at JetBrains.ActionManagement.ActionLoader.ActionLoader.Init_ActionXmlsAndHandlersFromAssemblies_Load(List`1 actionxmls, ICollection`1 actionhandlers, IApplicationDescriptor applicationDescriptor, IDictionary`2 mapIconClasses)
     at JetBrains.ActionManagement.ActionLoader.ActionLoader.<>c__DisplayClass10.<>c__DisplayClass14.<Init_ActionXmlsAndHandlersFromAssemblies>b__e()
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetime.AddBracket(Action FOpening, Action FClosing)
     at JetBrains.ActionManagement.ActionLoader.ActionLoader.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Init_ActionXmlsAndHandlersFromAssemblies>b__9(Lifetime lifetimeCatalog, IPartsCatalogue catalog)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ICollectionEventsEx.<>c__DisplayClass15`1.<>c__DisplayClass19.<ForEachItemCore>b__13()
     at JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
”

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = “
  Culture ID 8192 (0x2000) is not a supported culture.
  Parameter name: culture
”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException”
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  at JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.LogException(Exception ex)
     at JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ICollectionEventsEx.<>c__DisplayClass15`1.<ForEachItemCore>b__12(AddRemoveEventArgs`1 args)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.CollectionEvents`1.OnAcknowledgeSinkAddRemove(Action`1 handler, AddRemove addremove)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.CollectionEvents`1.<.ctor>b__0(Action`1 handler)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Infra.SignalWithDelegates`1.OnAfterAdvise(Action`1 handler)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<AdviseCore>b__0()
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetime.AddBracket(Action FOpening, Action FClosing)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.AdviseCore(Action`1 handler, Lifetime lifetime)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.Advise(Lifetime lifetime, Action`1 handler)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ICollectionEventsEx.ForEachItemCore[TValue](ICollectionEvents`1 thіs, Lifetime lifetime, Action`2 FHandlerA, Action`3 FHandlerB)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ICollectionEventsEx.ForEachItem[TValue](ICollectionEvents`1 thіs, Lifetime lifetime, Action`2 FHandler)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.CollectionEvents`1.View(Lifetime lifetime, Action`2 viewer)
     at JetBrains.ActionManagement.ActionLoader.ActionLoader.Init_ActionXmlsAndHandlersFromAssemblies(IPartsCatalogueSet catalogSet, IApplicationDescriptor applicationDescriptor)
     at JetBrains.VsIntegration.ActionManagement.VsActionLoader..ctor(Lifetime lifetime, VsActionManager actionManager, VsShortcutManager shortcutManager, IPartsCatalogueSet catalogSet, IApplicationDescriptor applicationDescriptor, ProductConfigurations productConfigurations, DTE dte)
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct& signature, IntPtr declaringType)
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeConstructor(Object[] args, SignatureStruct signature, RuntimeTypeHandle declaringType)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstanceOf(Type type, IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstance(IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.CreateInstanceChecked(OnError onError, IComponentContainer container)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.GetValue()
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SignatureResolution.BindArguments(List`1 argumentDescriptors)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstanceOf(Type type, IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstance(IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.CreateInstanceChecked(OnError onError, IComponentContainer container)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.GetValue()
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SignatureResolution.BindArguments(List`1 argumentDescriptors)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstanceOf(Type type, IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstance(IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.CreateInstanceChecked(OnError onError, IComponentContainer container)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.GetValue()
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SignatureResolution.BindArguments(List`1 argumentDescriptors)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstanceOf(Type type, IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Extensibility.PartComponentDescriptor.CreateInstance(IValueResolveContext context)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.CreateInstanceChecked(OnError onError, IComponentContainer container)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.SingletonDescriptor.GetValue()
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.ComponentStorage.InstantiateDescriptors(IEnumerable`1 descriptors)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.ComponentStorage.ComposeDescriptors(ICollection`1 descriptors)
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.ComponentStorage.Compose()
     at JetBrains.Application.Components.ComponentContainer.Compose()
     at JetBrains.Application.Env.RunsProducts.RunProduct(Lifetime lifetimeProduct, IApplicationDescriptor product, IEnumerable`1 enumProgramConfigurationsProviders, JetEnvironment environment, IDictionaryEvents`2 productsNonComposed, IDictionaryEvents`2 productsComposed)
     at JetBrains.Application.Env.RunsProducts.<>c__DisplayClass19.<Init_RunWhenAllowed>b__18(Lifetime lifetimeProduct, IApplicationDescriptor product)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ICollectionEventsEx.<>c__DisplayClass15`1.<>c__DisplayClass19.<ForEachItemCore>b__13()
     at JetBrains.Util.Logging.Logger.Catch(Action action)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ICollectionEventsEx.<>c__DisplayClass15`1.<ForEachItemCore>b__12(AddRemoveEventArgs`1 args)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.NotifySinks(TValue payload)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.Fire(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.CollectionEvents`1.FireAddRemove(AddRemove action, TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.CollectionEvents`1.InternalAdd(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.CollectionEvents`1.Add(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ICollectionEventsEx.Add[TValue](ICollectionEvents`1 thіs, Lifetime lifetime, TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.Application.Env.RunsProducts.<>c__DisplayClass7.<>c__DisplayClass9.<Init_CollectProductsAllowedToRun>b__5(Lifetime lifeVerdict, ProductCanBeStartedVerdict verdict)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.IPropertyEx.<>c__DisplayClass26`1.<>c__DisplayClass28.<ForEachValue>b__25(Lifetime lifetimeValue)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.SequentialLifetimes.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Next>b__2(LifetimeDefinition definition, Lifetime lifetime)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Lifetimes.Define(Lifetime lifetime, String id, Action`2 FAtomic, ILogger logger)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.SequentialLifetimes.DefineNext(Action`2 FNext)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.SequentialLifetimes.Next(Action`1 FNext)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.IPropertyEx.<>c__DisplayClass26`1.<ForEachValue>b__24(PropertyChangedEventArgs`1 args)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.NotifySinks(TValue payload)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.Fire(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.FireChange(TValue old, TValue new, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.SetValue(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.set_Value(TValue value)
     at JetBrains.Application.ComposeVerdictWithPriority.UpdateActiveTellers[TVerdict](Lifetime lifetimeComponent, List`1 tellers, IProperty`1 propComposite)
     at JetBrains.Application.ComposeVerdictWithPriority.<>c__DisplayClassc`1.<UpdateActiveTellers>b__a()
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.IPropertySignalEx.<>c__DisplayClass1f`1.<Advise_NoAcknowledgement>b__1e(PropertyChangedEventArgs`1 args)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.NotifySinks(TValue payload)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.Fire(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.FireChange(TValue old, TValue new, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.SetValue(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.IPropertyEx.<>c__DisplayClasse`2.<FlowInto>b__d(PropertyChangedEventArgs`1 args)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.NotifySinks(TValue payload)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.Fire(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.FireChange(TValue old, TValue new, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.SetValue(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.Application.DataFlowEx.<>c__DisplayClass23`1.<FlowIntoGuarded_NoReplay>b__22()
     at JetBrains.Threading.ReentrancyGuard.Execute(String name, Action action)
     at JetBrains.Threading.ReentrancyGuard.ExecuteOrQueue(String name, Action action)
     at JetBrains.Application.DataFlowEx.<>c__DisplayClass23`1.<FlowIntoGuarded_NoReplay>b__21()
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.ISignalEx.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<Advise>b__0(TValue value)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.NotifySinks(TValue payload)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Signal`1.Fire(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.FireChange(TValue old, TValue new, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.DataFlow.Property`1.SetValue(TValue value, Object cookie)
     at JetBrains.VsIntegration.Application.VsNonZombiedProductCanBeStarted.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__0()
     at JetBrains.VsIntegration.Application.VsNonZombiedProductCanBeStarted.<>c__DisplayClass4.<.ctor>b__2(VSSPROPID vsspropid, Object o)
     at JetBrains.VsIntegration.Interop.Shim.Shell.IVsShell.ShellPropertyChangesSink.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShellPropertyEvents.OnShellPropertyChange(Int32 propid, Object var)
”
```

[snipped - there were many more exceptions in the log....]

Any idea, what is causing this? Or how I can fix it?

Comment: Related? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c088b30-fe85-46e3-9506-50819ed3a7c8/error-culture-id-2155-0x086b-is-not-a-supported-culture?forum=clr

Comment: Thank you @jessehouwing I have been on that site myself and don't see the value thereof. Im working with Windows 10 (version 1703) not Windows (Server) 2003. Furthermore, on that list of culture IDs (and on the linked more extensive list) I can't find the ominous culture ID 8192.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who would have thought, that the solution is so simple. I vaguely remembered setting a new language locale on my system prior to going on holiday. After returning from said holiday, the phenomenon described in the question started.

### Solution

1. Remove the language locale en-CH (english Switzerland) and set the default en-US.
2. Restart the PC.
3. Problem solved.